# Choosing approach to periodically synchronize data with server in android

Tags: android, task

A have an application that displays some data from server. I also need to get data from server periodically (with different pauses, though) to cache it, and in some cases send notifications. 
Notifications can be **very important**, so situation when I use service and it gets killed for some reasons and cache time is skipped should not appear *(or, if it's not possible, I should minimize that skipped time)*. This caching process should start after system boot *(no matter if the application is running)* and be executed always when device is switched on.
So what approach should I use?

Answer (score 0):

In you case the most appropriate would be to use a `Service` for constantly update the data from the data source. as for the data it self, I think that in your case you are better with creating a `SQLite` DB in order to preserve your data over System reboots.

Comment: I thought about it, but service can be killed sometimes. Isn't alarm manager or some other approach more reliable?

Comment: you can use the alarm manager to start your services again in case it was killed by the OS, but the data sync should be done using the service AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I used Service like this

this may help you

```
public class MyService extends Service {

int counter = 0;
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000; // / 1000 = 1 second
private Timer timer = new Timer();
JsonParsers jsonParser = new JsonParsers();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String url_create_product = "http://ayyappagold.com/ayyappa/index.php";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not implemented...this sample is only for starting and stopping
    // services.
    // Service binding will be covered in another tutorial
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // Announcement about starting
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting the Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Start a Background thread
    doSomethingRepeatedly();

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void doSomethingRepeatedly() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            doIn();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            String month = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            String year = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String day = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            String months = null;
            if (month.startsWith("0") || month.startsWith("1")) {
                if (day.startsWith("0") || day.startsWith("1")
                        || day.startsWith("2") || day.startsWith("3")) {
                    months = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                }
            } else {
                months = year + "-" + "0" + month + "-0" + day;
            }
            loadJewelDetails(months);

        }
    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping the Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void set_alarm(int year, int month, int day, String title,
        String text, String billno) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("text", text);
    intent.putExtra("billno", billno);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 1234, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); // cancel any existing alarms

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,

            pendingIntent);

    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    db.insertFlg(1, billno);
}

public void loadJewelDetails(String month) {

    try {

        Cursor cursor = null;

        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

        cursor = db.getGoldPush(month);
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String billno = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String title = "Ayyappa Gold";
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("items"));

                    String dates = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("date"));

                    String yr = dates.substring(0, 4);
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
                    String mon = dates.substring(5);
                    String mo = mon.substring(0, 2);
                    int months = Integer.parseInt(mo);
                    String da = dates.substring(9);
                    int day = Integer.parseInt(da);

                    String tex = name.replace("*", "\n");

                    String text = tex;

                    // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date,
                    // this
                    // activity talks to the client that talks to the
                    // service
                    int flg = getFlag(billno);
                    if (flg == 0) {
                        set_alarm(year, months, day, title, text, billno);
                    }
                    System.out.println(dates);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // looping through All Contacts

}

public int getFlag(String bill) {
    int flag = 0;
    try {

        Cursor cursor = null;

        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

        cursor = db.getFlag(bill);
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    flag = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("flag")));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // looping through All Contacts
    return flag;
}

public void doIn() {

    // Building Parameters
    int id = getId();
    String name = String.valueOf(id);
    Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
    System.out.println("read the Gold and Silver rate details");

    JSONArray jsonarr = null;

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", name));

    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
            "POST", params);

    // check log cat fro response
    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    // check for success tag
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            jsonarr = json.getJSONArray("ayyappagolddetails");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                String billno = c.getString("id");
                String item = c.getString("items");
                String date = c.getString("date");
                String time = c.getString("time");
                db.addGoldItemDetails(billno, item, date, time);

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getId() {
    int id = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("read the id value");
        Cursor cursor = null;

        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

        cursor = db.getId();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("id")));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // looping through All Contacts
    System.out.println("last id value is" + id);
    return id;
}
```

}